# libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: synaptic

I am trying to install hacketyhack software:

http://hackety.com/

But i get an issue when installing thir script,

```
libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked in synaptics and it is already installed, do you have any advice?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you running a 64bit version of Ubuntu? If so than you need to install the 32bit version of libjpeg via this command

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
```

It seems hacketyhack uses the 32bit version of libjpeg

Comment: That worked perfectly on 64bit Linux Mint.

Comment: For me this doesn't work (I have Ubuntu 14.04). Apt-get says: "libjpeg62:i386 is already the newest version.
libjpeg62:i386 set to manually installed."
When I try to locate the file I get:
locate libjpeg.so.62
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
I need the file to import caffe in python. Can I somehow point python to the file?

Comment: Worked form me w/o specifying `i386` platform @ artful

Answer (score 8):

If the command in accepted answer doesn't work try using the following command

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg62`

It installs amd64 version of libjpeg62 which may be the case for some.